# R - base plot - shaded area around graph

Tags: r, plot, polygon

I have a simple line plot with fast data (grey) and a running mean of that data as the black solid line. What I would like to do is to shade the area along that black line 0.5 into the one and 0.5 into the other direction. The two dashed lines mark the boundaries of the wanted shaded area. I am trying it using `polygon`, but for some reason this does not work and I am clueless why.

Sample data (100 datapoints from the original data set, I hope that is sufficient):

```
xval,yval,runm
6.92232415850722,10223.1125440397,NA
6.97567055289054,10223.7940848759,NA
6.91987356947236,10224.4756257122,NA
6.76408889711752,10225.1571665485,NA
6.69498880703767,10225.8387073847,NA
6.73407232556043,10226.520248221,NA
6.77665179394136,10227.2017890573,NA
6.84275534062916,10227.8833298935,NA
6.8879116658316,10228.5648707298,NA
6.859664327829,10229.2464115661,NA
6.86841847225654,10229.9279524023,NA
6.87241424834036,10230.6094932386,NA
6.78738263324557,10231.2910340749,NA
6.7050107966374,10231.9725749112,NA
6.69077532290084,10232.6541157474,6.73282226315015
6.69285494365725,10233.3356565837,6.72268220267283
6.62670064675813,10234.01719742,6.71179512591555
6.53093184908463,10234.6987382562,6.70253770914134
6.58924635285394,10235.3802790925,6.69925694996729
6.65040546246993,10236.0618199288,6.69745327131799
6.58506323087209,10236.743360765,6.69173700699822
6.56402697098527,10237.4249016013,6.68353590094177
6.64572157610832,10238.1064424376,6.67203615987758
6.64300749410918,10238.7879832738,6.65723867033863
6.60448531596631,10239.4695241101,6.64390128414206
6.68744482436378,10240.1510649464,6.62987409509451
6.77653122345591,10240.8326057827,6.61481449411185
6.77982596642602,10241.5141466189,6.60349559698926
6.70034395646111,10242.1956874552,6.59484601818669
6.60607516873503,10242.8772282915,6.58630743931765
6.61812234418761,10243.5587691277,6.57777301300167
6.64905825017204,10244.240309964,6.57106905111653
6.64215106624629,10244.9218508003,6.56731069350767
6.6656661218959,10245.6033916365,6.56115889417799
6.64087844755865,10246.2849324728,6.55206561208198
6.56258439596747,10246.9664733091,6.54615687116913
6.53061861224771,10247.6480141453,6.54364352434563
6.49776310870341,10248.3295549816,6.53753626694185
6.44398697966327,10249.0110958179,6.5303866690769
6.45954274193178,10249.6926366542,6.5253855499697
6.44760280082999,10250.3741774904,6.51706498590221
6.42062621886073,10251.0557183267,6.50518371164912
6.44781571956776,10251.737259163,6.49279896061664
6.44552343256037,10252.4187999992,6.48280479268503
6.4346179568295,10253.1003408355,6.47654760683055
6.43682215417811,10253.7818816718,6.46887102304387
6.42558179020368,10254.463422508,6.45866609866778
6.41818112081901,10255.1449633443,6.44936275229822
6.40469237296339,10255.8265041806,6.44035921303931
6.37760699958962,10256.5080450168,6.43222122081491
6.40780100348678,10257.1895858531,6.42757789813851
6.48862656628022,10257.8711266894,6.42546284496523
6.46250385399501,10258.5526675257,6.42427938251218
6.42851955816049,10259.2342083619,6.42336656112931
6.45445174275044,10259.9157491982,6.42218255079228
6.43782790233887,10260.5972900345,6.42271832686576
6.42009299586329,10261.2788308707,6.42411200946439
6.40828343545173,10261.960371707,6.42358845888727
6.40051891851261,10262.6419125433,6.42288666527028
6.41835959310065,10263.3234533795,6.42330761378413
6.38782483058741,10264.0049942158,6.42433897848796
6.34291051888921,10264.6865350521,6.42359033379822
6.3630506751594,10265.3680758883,6.42102732130494
6.39555994412865,10266.0496167246,6.42059540146731
6.39673868082688,10266.7311575609,6.42200966068561
6.42328471567517,10267.4126983972,6.42010528403423
6.46716701704941,10268.0942392334,6.41246137794253
6.46225923511201,10268.7757800697,6.40430946548378
6.41660233817708,10269.457320906,6.39819636499828
6.42402243182104,10270.1388617422,6.39399224749757
6.46367608303422,10270.8204025785,6.39208376519963
6.4624366968196,10271.5019434148,6.39065706450328
6.43210920225426,10272.183484251,6.38782977792963
6.42446962405071,10272.8650250873,6.38305528599779
6.44724641224506,10273.5465659236,6.37801017143837
6.4677630952928,10274.2281067599,6.37457292997379
6.40312244951144,10274.9096475961,6.37452990112091
6.34129074602072,10275.5911884324,6.37638709638177
6.39173477783444,10276.2727292687,6.37667201948967
6.42003477613879,10276.9542701049,6.37556556763871
6.35066970394522,10277.6358109412,6.37332223702913
6.25930938352939,10278.3173517775,6.3701624857799
6.21794648023232,10278.9988926137,6.36742649250264
6.24512654359568,10279.68043345,6.36439918202126
6.32832821772913,10280.3619742863,6.35976149094678
6.38057343340059,10281.0435151225,6.3548329663133
6.37729197497268,10281.7250559588,NA
6.32346483824232,10282.4065967951,NA
6.25728416055731,10283.0881376314,NA
6.26700615631804,10283.7696784676,NA
6.28470758665022,10284.4512193039,NA
6.34161965330271,10285.1327601402,NA
6.41876653298508,10285.8143009764,NA
6.40410763736566,10286.4958418127,NA
6.36354512529815,10287.177382649,NA
6.35598479738773,10287.8589234852,NA
6.37237447957265,10288.5404643215,NA
6.38017943679403,10289.2220051578,NA
6.32578302373567,10289.903545994,NA
6.28489169958693,10290.5850868303,NA
6.31582034402957,10291.2666276666,NA
```

[image]

The code is as follows:

```
plot(dat$xval, dat$yval, pch=".", col="grey", ylab = "", xlab = "", type="l", xlim = c(5,8))
lines(rollmean(dat$xval, 30, fill=NA), dat$yval, col="black", lwd=2)

xmin <- c(rollmean(dat$xval, 30, fill=NA) - 0.5)
xmax <- c(rollmean(dat$xval, 30, fill=NA) + 0.5)

lines(xmin, dat$yval, col="black", lwd=2, lty = 2)
lines(xmax, dat$yval, col="black", lwd=2, lty = 2)

polygon(c(xmin, rev(xmax)), c(dat$yval, rev(dat$yval)), col = rgb(0, 0, 1, alpha = 0.3), border = NA)
```

And the outcome of the polygon command is this:

[image]

I don't have minimal example data, but maybe it is possible to see the error I am doing without it. It looks like that the upper end is connected to beginning instead of moving along the xaxis towards the end of xmax and then moving in reverse order back down how I thought it is supposed to.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include a small amount of sample data?

Comment: Added some 100 datapoints from the original dataset. not sure it that helps

Comment: Thanks for providing sample data. Unfortunately, the variable names in your same data (xval, yval, runm) don't appear in your code, and it is not obvious what plugs in where to create the solid and dashed lines. I wonder if your code is more complicated here than we need; for instance, I don't think `$leg` and `$lat` have anything to do with the plot, just how you get to the data _for_ the plot. I suggest you can reduce the code in this question substantially and still be able to use what code we may offer. I think the easiest way forward is to adapt your code to use this sample data. Okay?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I changed the code and the plots to be the same as the sample data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `rollmean` function inevitably produces `NA` values at the "edges" of `xmin` which `polygon` can't handle well.

If you leave them out explicitly, everything works as expected:

```r
plot(dat$xval, dat$yval, pch=".", col="grey", ylab="", xlab="", 
     type="l", xlim=c(5,8))
lines(rollmean(dat$xval, 30, fill=NA), dat$yval, col="black", lwd=2)

xmin <- c(rollmean(dat$xval, 30, fill=NA) - 0.5)
xmax <- c(rollmean(dat$xval, 30, fill=NA) + 0.5)

lines(xmin, dat$yval, col="black", lwd=2, lty=2)
lines(xmax, dat$yval, col="black", lwd=2, lty=2)

not.na <- !is.na(xmin)
polygon(c(xmin[not.na], rev(xmax[not.na])), 
        c(dat$yval[not.na], rev(dat$yval[not.na])), 
        col=rgb(0, 0, 1, alpha=0.3), border=NA)
```

[image: graph]

Comment: Thx a lot! That works perfectly. Always those NAs...

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're looking for?

```r
plot(dat$xval, dat$yval, pch=".", col="grey", ylab = "", xlab = "", type="l", xlim = c(5,8))
lines(zoo::rollmean(dat$xval, 30, fill=NA), dat$yval, col="black", lwd=2)
lines(xmin, dat$yval, col="black", lwd=2, lty = 2)
lines(xmax, dat$yval, col="black", lwd=2, lty = 2)
polygon(c(dat$xval - 0.5, rev(dat$xval) + 0.5), c(dat$yval, rev(dat$yval)),
        col = rgb(0, 0, 1, alpha = 0.3), border = NA)
```

[image]

Comment: Not exactly. I would need the shaded area between the two dashed lines. Or even better the shaded area that fits between the two dashed lines but without the lines. I have the feeling the problem has something to do with the NA values in the rollmean column

Comment: Your question says (and attempts) plus/minus 0.5, how did I misinterpret that?

Comment: Yes, plus/minus 0.5 of the black line, which is the running mean of the grey line

Comment: I didn't get to the fix in time, so much for multitasking ... :-/